# extract specific data from MYSQL in PHP file

Tags: php, mysql

i have sql database it's contain some data for clients 
it's contain two table all one contain different type of clients
this is the code i uses to extract data from table

```
    <?php
require_once("includes/connection.php");
    require_once("includes/functions.php");

$query  = "SELECT name, id, comit FROM co_form";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo "Name :{$row['name']} <br>" .
     "id : {$row['id']} <br>" .
     "comit : {$row['comit']} <br><br>";

} 
    mysql_close($connection); 

?>
```

the field comit divided clients to classes from 1 to 5
above code show all clients
i need to show only one class of it
i mean to show only clients with comit=1
i know it's easy but i can't doing this and I'm new in php

Comment: If you write new code, you should avoid mysql_* functions, because they're deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query  = "SELECT name, id, comit FROM co_form WHERE comit = 1";
```